# how to retrieve oracle 10G license key in windows?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

Is it possible to retrieve oracle license key in windows? It was supposed to be in the cd but the cd is missing.

any thoughts and advise?

Thanks

Comment: ? I've never encountered such a thing as an "Oracle license key" (that said, I've only installed Oracle from downloads, never from phyiscal media). What do you need it for? Have you tried contacting Oracle support?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt because right now our company would be migrating servers. we want to transfer the license.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: Who told you that you need a license key for migrating Oracle databases? And what are you supposed to do with this mysterious license key? Usually, all you need is your CSI number (Customer Support Identifier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a license key for the Oracle database. All that's relevant is

- how many licenses you bought (for your Customer Support Identifier)
- what machines you're running Oracle on

To find the number of licenses you own, you should log in to *My Oracle Support* and check your information there.

See [Oracle forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2231087?start=0&tstart=0) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Frank for the help